# AWS Elastic Beanstalk deploy using CLI having Botocore Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I got this error while I'm trying to deploy my project to AWS Elastic Beanstalk using CLI. This is the error I got:

Does anyone know what this error is? Thanks!

```
$ eb deploy
Alert: The platform version that your environment is using isn't recommended. There's a recommended version in the same platform branch.

Uploading: [########------------------------------------------] 17% 2020-07-21 14:36:42,196 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:36:59,354 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:37:20,237 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:37:49,380 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:38:52,916 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:38:53,199 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:39:20,861 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:39:47,738 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
2020-07-21 14:41:48,657 (ERROR) ebcli.lib.aws : Botocore Error
```

Answer (score 3):

Your application on EB executes on EB platform. There are many platform versions.
The versions get updated from time to time by AWS.

The error you are getting means that there is a new platform version, while you are trying to deploy to the old one instead.

Its not specified what platform do you use in your question, but the list of all current and previous platform versions is here:

- [Platform history](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/platforms/platform-history.html)

To check your platform you can do the following:

```
eb status | grep Platform
```

Example output:

```
Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3
```

Or run

```
eb config
```

Example output

```
ApplicationName: myenv
DateUpdated: 2020-07-21 05:00:09+00:00
EnvironmentName: my-new-env
PlatformArn: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Python 3.7 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.0.3
```

Thus its recommended to change your platform to the current one.

To select a default platform:

```
eb platform select
```

and follow the prompts.

Comment: Is there a way to show the recommend platform from the command line? The commands above just seem to show the current one without showing what to change to. (I suspect that `eb platform select` will not change my local configuration files but just change the EB settings online).